# Render dentro da página

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Galera sou novo em rails e estou tendo dificuldade com o RENDER

Eu tenho um render "_tables-cliente" dentro da página e quando eu mando executar um método, eu quero atualizar apenas o render específico e não a página inteira, tem como?

Comment: Tente usar render partial ex. nesse link http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html e http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html ele vai fazer o reload na página mas vai salvar a sessão as informações imputadas

Comment: conseguiu resolver esse problema? consegue postar um trecho do seu código para demonstrar o que você quer fazer? leia mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o método AJAX `.load()`, selecionando apenas o que deseja atualizar e buscando dados atualizados em seu controller pela URL, podendo também passar parâmetros.

```
$(selector).load(URL,data,callback);
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp